# How to exclude resources with a specific rdf:type from SPARQL results?

Tags: java, rdf, sparql, semantic-web, rdfs

I have this query SPARQL that I ran on it.dbpedia.org/sparql:

```sql
select ?resource where {
  ?resource rdfs:label "Piemonte"@it
}
```

I get this result:

```
http://it.dbpedia.org/resource/Categoria:Piemonte
http://it.dbpedia.org/resource/Piemonte
```

I would like to have only http://it.dbpedia.org/resource/Piemonte as a result. I am trying to write this query SPARQL to delete [http://it.dbpedia.org/resource/Categoria:Piemonte](http://it.dbpedia.org/resource/Categoria%3aPiemonte) from the results:

```
select ?resource where {
  ?resource rdfs:label "Piemonte"@it
  FILTER (rdf:type != skos:Concept)
}
```

because I noticed that [http://it.dbpedia.org/resource/Categoria:Piemonte](http://it.dbpedia.org/resource/Categoria%3aPiemonte) has the object `skos:Concept` whereas the http://it.dbpedia.org/resource/Piemonte doesn't, but I get the same result.  Why? What am I doing wrong here?

I also tries adding `LIMIT 1`, but the result was `http://it.dbpedia.org/resource/Categoria:Piemonte`, since the results aren't guaranteed to be in the same order.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With a filter like `FILTER (rdf:type != skos:Concept)` you're just asking whether two constants are unequal.  The URIs `rdf:type` and `skos:Concept` are, of course, different.

What you want is a resource that doesn't have the value `skos:Concept` for the property `rdf:type`.  You'd indicate that it *does* have that by `?resource rdf:type skos:Concept`.  So your query just needs a filter that ensures that that triple does not exist in the data. On the Italian DBpedia, you can ask the following and get just one result back.

```sql
select ?resource where {
  ?resource rdfs:label "Piemonte"@it
  filter not exists { ?resource rdf:type skos:Concept }
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://it.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=select%20?resource%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20?resource%20rdfs:label%20%22Piemonte%22@it%0D%0A%20%20filter%20not%20exists%20%7B%20?resource%20a%20skos:Concept%20%7D%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&debug=on)

Comment: It works! I have another question. If I write this query:
prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix skos: <http://www.w3.org/2009/08/skos-reference/skos.html#>
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
select ?resource where {
?resource rdfs:label "Piemonte"@it
filter not exists { ?resource rdf:type skos:Concept }
}

I get this SPARQL result:
http://it.dbpedia.org/resource/Categoria:Piemonte
http://it.dbpedia.org/resource/Piemonte

Why? What is the difference between two queries? I have added only the prefixes!

Comment: I have resolved in this way:

prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
select ?resource where {
  ?resource rdfs:label "Piemonte"@it
  filter not exists { ?resource rdf:type skos:Concept }
}


I had wrong the skos prefix.

Comment: @Musich87 Comments are for requesting clarification on a question/answer, if you have new questions ask them as new questions linking back to your original question as a reference where relevant